# Create content which updates asynchronously PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to create a trading bot with PHP.
I would like to get the value of the currency and update it even without refreshing the page.

In order to do this I should execute this call every 5-10 seconds.
Is that correct?

```
$summ = $d->getMarketSummary("USDT-BTC");
```

Is there a way to do this asynchronously? Even if user doesn't reload the whole page.

I've heard of AJAX, but it's Javascript.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ajax intro https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've heard it correctly, you need to do this in JavaScript, with AJAX. There are two parts for this:

1) You need to make an API in PHP, a route that will only respond with the data you want. So a page that when called:

```
<?php
$summ = $d->getMarketSummary("USDT-BTC");
echo $summ;
?>
```

And mapped to a url, let's say `/data`.

2) You need to make a JS in your page that calls that newly created route every-so-often; for that your need to use ajax (xmlhttprequest or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)), and use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to call it regularly and update the data in your page accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much. Is it correct if i assign $summ to $_GET["sum"] into the new page?

Comment: @FilippoMomentè AFAIK, you shouldn't assign anything to the `$_GET`, only use it to access the Query Params from the receiving request ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use javascript (AJAX) for this task, your only way is to create a CRON job that fires that PHP script every minute. Unfortunatelly, CRON jobs can't be configured to execute every X seconds, but you can fire it all minutes of the day.